# Sending information to parent when popup closes, cross-domain

Tags: javascript, html

Im using this code to demonstrate the concept on same domains:

Parent:

```
<html>
    <body>
<form>
    <input id="details" name="details">
    <input type="button" name="choice" onClick="window.open('http://domainB.com/popuppage.html','popuppage','width=850,toolbar=1,resizable=1,scrollbars=yes,height=700,top=100,left=100');" value="Open popup">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

And the popup file:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
<!-- Begin
function sendValue (s){
var selvalue = s.value;
window.opener.document.getElementById('details').value = selvalue;
window.close();
}
//  End -->
</script>
<form name="selectform">
<input name="details" value="">
<input type=button value="Copy input to parent opener" onClick="sendValue(this.form.details);">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

This works great, but because the popup make a modification of the content of the parent page `window.opener.document.getElementById('details').value = selvalue;` this will not work on a crossdomain example for security reasons. I dont want to modify content on parent, i just want to communicate a value to the parent script, so i need a listener script on parent to attend for information sent from the popup on close. Is this possible? alternatives?

Comment: why is your choices on the other domain? can't you make the same page on the same domain?

Comment: I cant, it has to be cross domain

Comment: This may be a choice: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.postMessage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Passerby suggested, postMessage (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.postMessage) is the ideal solution for what you want to do. Because it doesn't work on older browsers, you'll either have to limit your stuff to newer browsers or employ hacks with iframes and the like to achieve cross-domain communication.

You could run easyXDM in the popup and have it load domainA.com in an iframe, then from that iframe you should be able to access and manipulate the other page on domainA.com that initiated the popup.